# python tkinter refreshed data while running a function in the background

Tags: python, tkinter

ok so its quite difficult for me to explain but
i made this program, that web scrape bitcoin
now ive built a tkinter for it and i want the program to refresh the label everytime it scrapes the net
and at the same time check if the price have dropped to the price i set for it

i cant seem to understand how to make the tkinter update it self whilst checking if the price dropped from the original price without the program freezing,

here is the code

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import smtplib
import re
from time import sleep
from secret import mail,password,hd,rmail


root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Bitcoin Tracker")
root.geometry("900x506")
x=IntVar()


C=Canvas(root, bg="grey", height=900, width=506)
filename=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"C:\Users\Home\Documents\studying\webscraperpython\wallpaper.jpg"))
background_label=Label(root, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
C.pack()

label1=tk.Label(root,text="Time between each search: ",font="Helvetica 12 bold",fg="white",bg="#081E2C")
label1.place(x=200,y=10)
entry1=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=x)
entry1.place(x=420,y=10,height=23,width=200)

label2=tk.Label(root,text="",font="Helvetica 8 bold",fg="white",bg="#081E2C")
label2.place(x=0,y=100)

def scrape():
    wt=x.get()
    url="https://cointelegraph.com/bitcoin-price-index"
    headers= {hd}
    page=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

    total_price=soup.find("div",class_="summaryData").get_text()
    label2.config(text=total_price)    
    but2.place(x=400,y=150)
    label3=tk.Label(root,text="",font="Helvetica 8 bold",fg="white",bg="#081E2C")
    label3.place(x=400,y=350)
    url="https://cointelegraph.com/bitcoin-price-index"
    headers= {hd}
    page=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
    price=soup.find("span",class_="price-value").get_text()[1:].strip().replace(',','')
    non_decimal = re.compile(r'[^\d.]+')
    fprice=int(non_decimal.sub('', price))
    
def conti():
    wt=x.get()
    url="https://cointelegraph.com/bitcoin-price-index"
    headers= {hd}
    page=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
    price2=soup.find("span",class_="price-value").get_text()[1:].strip().replace(',','')
    non_decimal = re.compile(r'[^\d.]+')
    fprice2=int(non_decimal.sub('', price2))
    fprice3=float(fprice2*0.9)
    label2.config(text=("Current price is:",price2))
    root.after(wt*60,conti)
    
    def mail():
        if fprice2 <= fprice3:
            def alert_me(URL):
                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
                                
                server.ehlo()
                server.starttls()
                server.ehlo()
                                
                server.login(mail,password)
                                
                subject = 'Price fell down by 10 percent for bitcoin'
                body = 'data from: '+URL
                msg = f"Subject:{subject}\n\n{body}"
                                
                server.sendmail(mail,rmail,msg)
                
                server.quit()
            alert_me(url)
            
        else:
            url="https://cointelegraph.com/bitcoin-price-index"
            headers= {hd}
            page=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

            soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
            price4=soup.find("span",class_="price-value").get_text()[1:].strip().replace(',','')
            print("current price is" ,price4 )
        root.after(1000,mail)

but=tk.Button(root,text="Initialize",font="Helvetica 12",anchor="center",justify=CENTER,command=scrape)
but.place(x=1,y=50,width=898)

but2=tk.Button(root,text="Continue?",font="Helvetica 12",anchor="center",justify=CENTER,command=conti)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try to run the function again and again by using `root.after(100000,func)`

Comment: where should i locate the root.after ? and what does it mean to run it again and again? isnt there an option to run it till it get the if condition?

Comment: Your already using `after()`, whats the problem? Which function do you want to repeat? Just include that function instead of the whole code please